# How to integrate native iOS framework in react-native plugin?

Tags: react-native, npm

[image]I have created react-native package successfully but unable to created plugin.
After creating react-native plugin I have integrated third party library in outer ios folder and push it to npm.
But when i'm using this plugin in other react-native project I got this error
"No such module 3rd Party Library"

Comment: Please post your folder structure.
Your module has to be under node_modules doesn‘t matter if it‘s iOS only or not.

Comment: I've added folder structure.
Did you means my 3rd party library should be in node modules ?

Comment: Did you test your module locally? Did you try to import your module another project at your local machine ?

Comment: Yes , I tried with local as well with npm package.

Comment: Does it work locally? How do you import the module locally?

Comment: No, It's not works locally. 
I install package at root level by typing in terminal "npm i /plugin path". \n
And import by "import my-plugin from "/path to my-plugin"